# Understanding Relationship between Multiple <Precondition> Elements in Azure B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am currently working on an Azure B2C custom policy and have a question regarding the relationship between multiple  elements within .
Specifically, I would like to know if these elements have an 'AND' or 'OR' relationship.

```
<Preconditions>
  <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
    <Value>extension_isMigrated</Value>
    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
  </Precondition>
  <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
    <Value>extension_isMigrated</Value>
    <Value>False</Value>
    <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
  </Precondition>
</Preconditions>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/userjourneys#preconditions), "Azure AD B2C evaluates the preconditions in list order. The order-based preconditions allows you set the order in which the preconditions are applied. The first precondition that satisfied overrides all the subsequent preconditions. The orchestration step is executed only if all of the preconditions are not satisfied."

**Update**

You can't check against "null". Use ClaimsExist.

```
<Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>email</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
      <Value>phone</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
```

If email doesn't exist, skip. If phone doesn't exist, skip.

Otherwise, execute step.

Comment: want to check am i do it right:
https://github.com/nullmicgo/stackoverview-questions/blob/main/question001.xml

Logic:
- If both email and phone are empty, perform ACTION_OTP_001.
- If email is not empty and phone is empty, perform ACTION_OTP_002.
- If email is empty and phone is not empty, perform ACTION_OTP_003.
- If both email and phone are not empty, perform ACTION_OTP_004.